# Checking inputs of form in django before submit

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am using Django and try to submit a form.
I have a "call-us" form and there is 3 fields.
I want to make this, If one of the fields is empty, and the user clicked on Submit button, don't send the info to View and warm the user that they must complete the required fields.

here is my form:

```html
<form role="form" action="{% url "landingpages:callusthanks" %}" method="post" style="max-width: 500px;margin: 0 auto;margin-top: 30px;">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
            <input type="text"  name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></div>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></div>
            <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-6">
            <button type="submit" class="form-control">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one option you can use jQuery [validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) and set the required fields like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#your_form_id").validate({
       rules :{
            your_field : {
            required : true
            }
            .....
       },
       messages :{
            your_field : {
            required : 'your_field is required'
            }
            .....
       }
    });
});
```

***Edit***: Just saw you said not to send to view. So, ignore this but I'll leave it for future reference on the off chance that it's useful.

Preferably, you could turn this into a `form` import it from `forms.py` and then send it to your view. You could then just set which fields are required.